# Why doesn't sshd use a pseudo terminal when the ssh client's argument is followed by an interactive program?

Tags: ssh, pty

The normal way to connect to an SSH server is `ssh username@ip_address`. But a user may only want to run a program on the remote machine. So the program name follows after the normal argument which is `ssh username@ip_address <program_name>`. For example, `ssh username@ip_address ls`. That argument is fine except for interactive programs (that also accept user input as well as providing output) e.g. `top`. The output is

> TERM environment variable not set.

which means no (pseudo-)terminal is attached between the sshd and top programs. The solution is to add argument `-t` where the whole command now becomes `ssh -t username@ip_address top`.

My question is why can't sshd by default also use a pseudo-terminal to communicate with non-interactive programs so there is no need to add the `-t` argument for interactive programs?

Comment: The short answer is "because that's usually not what you want".

Comment: I predict your question will get moderated for essentially begging an opinion/making a gripe. But Let's flip the question around: why should ssh allocate tty resources when it's not required in a vast majority of cases? The REAL question is: why isn't force-tty allocation a config option so you can make it a default or host-specific default?

Comment: @Otheus It **is** config option. You can set `RequestTTY yes` (or `force`) in your config.

Comment: Er indeed. Seems to have been introduced in 6 but buggy until shortly after. I only use very old distributions. :)

Comment: How can SSH reliably know that a program is interactive? Even `top` can run in batch mode.

Comment: @ThomasDickey : That is unlikely.  What is much more likely is that they document their reasons somewhere else.  e.g. [the site they actually use for development](http://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/ssh/) or their mailing lists.

Answer (score 18):

It's true that, as others have said, PTYs have a certain overhead - but the big reason for not using a PTY when running a remote command is that you lose information.

Normally, when you run a command remotely via ssh, the command's `stdout` and `stderr` streams are sent to the local `stdout` and `stderr`, which means you can redirect/pipe them separately - for example:

```
$ ssh server ls foo bar
ls: cannot access bar: No such file or directory
foo
$ ssh server ls foo bar > stdout 2> stderr
$ cat stdout
foo
$ cat stderr
ls: cannot access bar: No such file or directory
```

But if you use a PTY, all output goes to `stdout`, because PTYs don't have separate streams for output/error:

```
$ ssh -t server ls foo bar > stdout 2> stderr
$ cat stdout
ls: cannot access bar: No such file or directory
foo
$ cat stderr
$
```

Comment: This is a good point I was not aware of.

Comment: @ThomasDickey: Hardly... the question is not "what is the historical reason behind the developers' choice of this default", but "why *can't* sshd use a pseudo-terminal by default" (the emphasis is mine, but the wording is more or less direct from the question). So the difference in behaviour (which would break a number of scripting idioms) is relevant, independent of how the developers made that choice :-)

Comment: @ThomasDickey: Have you even *read* the question? Where does it mention the opinion of the developers?

Comment: +1 points out a specific advantage of *not* using a pty (other than performance).  You could still argue that `-t` should be the default, and an option required to turn it off, so really the minor performance advantage is what makes most sense to me for cases where it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 7):

Manual page for `ssh` describes this:

> When the user's identity has been accepted by the server, the server either *executes the given command in a non-interactive session* or, *if no command has been specified, logs into the machine and gives the user a normal shell as an interactive session*.  All communication with the remote command or shell will be automatically encrypted.

It is feature and probably caused by historical reasons of `rsh` behaviour. It is pretty reasonable. Most of the commands are really not interactive and it is not free operation to allocate PTY (which was more important 20 years back).

Comment: Resource issues are plausible, but the comment about `rsh` is obscure since that program has no corresponding option.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I never used `rsh`, but there certainly there is some influence, not in the options, but in behaviour of `rsh` and `rlogin` (if there is command or not). [*You cannot run an interactive command (like rogue(6) or vi(1)) using rsh; use rlogin(1) instead.*](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsh).

Answer (score 1):

How is `ssh` suppose to tell if the command you are invoking is interactive or not?

This nightmare is made worse when you realize you could be logging into a machine running a non-unix OS.

There being no easy solution one case had to be the default.

Comment: It does not know. It can't know. And therefore we have manual page which describes behaviour in these situations.